# Easiest way to add jQuery functions to jqMobi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel, jqmobi, appframework

I'm trying to get started with jqMobi. I really like it's size and speed, but it is missing a couple jQuery functions.

How can I "import" some functions from jQuery to jqMobi? Is this possible?

The functions I need right now are `.wrap()`, `.wrapAll()` and `.contents()`

Any help porting those functions to jqMobi or general tips on how to do it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just import jQuery? If you need something more lightweight and not the full jQuery you can use Zepto or some other alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at Zepto, but I need to support Windows 8 Mobile. Zepto does not support it.

Comment: I found a solution for my current need, right now I only need the wrapInner function.

$.fn.wrapInner = function (wrapper) {
    org_html = this.html();
    elm_wrapper = $(wrapper);
    new_html = wrapper + org_html + "</" + elm_wrapper[0].tagName + ">";
    this.html(new_html);
};

However, I'd still be really interested if there is a standard way to import jQuery functions to jqMobi.